# How to properly create different logins for different Modules in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

In my Yii 1.x application I defined new `Admin` module. In the `init` method of the `admin` module I defined new `user` component like this:

```
$this->setComponents(array(
            'user'=>array(
                'class' => 'CWebUser',
                // enable cookie-based authentication
                'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                'baseUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/user/login"),
                'stateKeyPrefix' => '_admin',
            ),
        ));
```

Now, I expect I can do the following:

```
Yii::app()->getModule("admin")->user->login($this->_identity,$duration)
```

or

```
Yii::app()->getModule("admin")->user->logout();
```

but it is not working.

When I print my module (`var_dump(Yii::app()>getModule("admin"))`) I can see that `user` component is not defined.

```
object(AdminModule)[14]
  public 'defaultController' => string 'default' (length=7)
  public 'layout' => null
  public 'controllerNamespace' => null
  public 'controllerMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_controllerPath' (CWebModule) => null
  private '_viewPath' (CWebModule) => null
  private '_layoutPath' (CWebModule) => null
  public 'preload' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'behaviors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_id' (CModule) => string 'admin' (length=10)
  private '_parentModule' (CModule) => null
  private '_basePath' (CModule) => string '/srv/www/htdocs/public/project/application/protected/modules/admin' (length=71)
  private '_modulePath' (CModule) => null
  private '_params' (CModule) => null
  private '_modules' (CModule) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_moduleConfig' (CModule) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_components' (CModule) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_componentConfig' (CModule) => 
    array (size=1)
      'user' => 
        array (size=4)
          'class' => string 'CWebUser' (length=8)
          'allowAutoLogin' => boolean true
          'baseUrl' => string '/project/application/index.php/admin/user/login' (length=52)
          'stateKeyPrefix' => string '_admin' (length=11)
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, code from working project.
Defined user component in module main class:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->setImport(array(
        'admin.models.*',
        'admin.components.*',
    ));
    Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
        'user'=>array(
            'class'=>'AdminWebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginRequiredAjaxResponse'=>'Dear admin, your session expired, login and try again',
            'stateKeyPrefix'=>'admin_',
            'authTimeout'=>14400,
        ),      
    ), false);
}
```

and default user component defined in main config file:

```
'user'=>array(
    'class'=>'WebUser',
    'loginRequiredAjaxResponse'=>'Your session expired, login and try again',
    'autoRenewCookie'=>false,
    'allowAutoLogin'=>false,
    'stateKeyPrefix'=>'user_',
    'loginUrl'=>'/home/login',
),
```

So you can *"have two sessions for one user"* depending on module (in module other session, in root -other). For example `var_dump(Yii::app()->user->stateKeyPrefix)` out of module gives `user_`, but in module gives `admin_`.
**In fact yii uses the same session file, but sets and gets data depending on `stateKeyPrefix`** (when we use `setState()` or `getState()` ).

So If you keep `userName` in `admin` module using `Yii::app()->user->setState('userName', 'John')`, it puts in session file `'admin_userName' => 'John'`, it means you can get that value out of `admin` module (for example in root) by using **`Yii::app()->session->get('admin_userName')`**.
If you try to get it (out of module) using `getState` it can not return you the correct value, because it must find `user_userName` (because in root, for user component `'stateKeyPrefix' => 'user_'`) instead of `admin_userName`.

Thank you and sorry for long expression ))

Comment: Aha, difference is that in the first version you called $this->setComponents and in this one Yii::app()->setComponents(). I've check how it is done in Gii module, and yep Yii::app()->setComponents() is used and should work.

Comment: @Mr.M
Ah, sorry, I haven't been carefully that uses `$this`, I copied your code and set second parameter ))

Comment: I will test and will let you know if it is working, but I'm sure it will!

Answer (score 1):

By default method [`setComponents`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponents-detail) (`setComponent`) checks if component already defined it only merge new params with old ones.
So you must set second parameter to `false` for redefining new component (components):

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->setComponents(array(
        'user'=>array(
            'class' => 'CWebUser',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'baseUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/user/login"),
            'stateKeyPrefix' => '_admin',
        ),
    ), false);
}
```

> By the way, inside the module you can use component without calling
>   module:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
Yii::app()->user->logout();
```

Comment: I thought it will work, but it is not working, even when I put FALSE as second parameter. Any other sugestion or working example?

Comment: @Mr.M
I add a new answer with piece of code from working project.